# How to use jackson's context in streaming json?

Tags: java, json, parsing, stream, jackson

I am using the Jackson streaming JSON parser.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "foo": {...},
    "bar": {...}
}
```

I want to know when I am done processing the top level "foo" node (`{...}`).

Current thoughts:

- Use `JsonStreamContext` and find when there the context is the same as when I started. This makes some equality assumptions (that the context before and after are equal), which I'm not sure are true. Honestly, I'm not sure what this class is for.
- Keep a count of when I enter and exit arrays/objects. Increment when I enter; decrement when I leave. When the count hits 0, I am at the same "level" as I started.

Am I on the right track? What is the way this is supposed to be done with the API?

Answer (score 0):

Methods you mention work, although you could also simply do recursive-descent matching (each START_OBJECT matched with END_OBJECT), and use `parser.skipValue()` for entries that you do not care about (it'll skip from current START_OBJECT/ARRAY to matching END_OBJECT/ARRAY; or, for other tokens, stay at current location).